# Laptop keyboards are USB or PS2 devices?

Tags: laptop, usb, keyboard, ps2

I know they use a flat cable to connecto to the motherboard, but logically, are they USB or PS2 devices?

Comment: In my laptop, specifically, it is PS2. But is this true for all/most laptops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess modern laptops probably connect them through the USB bus, although i don't know with any certainty.
You should be able to check on yours if you open Device Manager and under View on the menu select `Devices by connection`. then it is just a matter of clicking through the connections until you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the laptop, but yes, the hardware inspection tool on your operating system should be able to tell you.